# Is there a limit to the max value or number of digits that can be stored in a Pandas cell when importing and concatenating files?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I import/read file on daily basis and then concat it and store/save it.
Same next day and this way db is created in csv.

When I import/read indivu=idual file the tunover column shows actual figures but when I concat it and store as db, then tunover values above some (unkown values only) turn negative. is there any limit to max value or number of digits that can be stored in pandas cell.

I rechecked all the code and read files individually and in csv db and then in pandas for any mistake but all things are fine.

I want the number as it is. Above certain value of turnpver in pandas the figure is shoen as -2147483648 common for all cells where the values exceeds the particular threshold value.

Comment: It depends on the type you use.